# Does Kendo have a vertical multiselect combo box?

Tags: kendo-ui, multi-select, kendo-dropdown

I really like the style of this one
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/forms/multiselect-1/ but I can't seem to find a similar control on Kendo Angular.

Does anyone know how I could create this behavior? (Dropdown with checkboxes)

I'd like to use this drop down as search options

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a specific widget but a good workaround would be to configure a kendoDropDownTree to behave a bit like the multiselect in your link.  (Note that all list items are placed at the root of the dataSource)

```
<div id="example">
    <div id="cap-view" class="demo-section k-content">
        <h4>Select one or more items</h4>
        <input id="dropdowntree" style="width: 100%;" />
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#dropdowntree").kendoDropDownTree({
                placeholder: "Select ...",
                checkboxes: true,
                checkAll: true,
                autoClose: false,
                dataSource: [
                    { text: "Option 1" },
                    { text: "Option 2" },
                    { text: "Option 3" }
                ]
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Appreciate the reply. This could work, however I don't see the dropdowntree in the Angular UI widgets. This appears to be jquery only.